# Tye Mismatch Error Closing a Collection

Tags: vb6-migration

I receive a "Type Mismatch" error on the following line of code.

```
Set colClaims = Nothing
```

Earlier pertinent code is as follows:

```
Public colClaims As New Collection
```

....

```
Dim oClaimRecord As IClaimRecord
```

...

```
Set UB01 = oClaimRecord.ParseInput(psInputRecord)
```

...

```
colClaims.Add UB01, sIndex, psBefore
```

...

I am very confused as to how there can be a type mismatch error when closing a collection.  Can anyone offer any direction?  Thank you

Comment: I'm confused. Are you writing vb6 or vb.net code? Based on the tags, I am assuming vb.net - but your code looks like vb6.  In vb.net, the `set` statement is not required.

Comment: It's vb6.  Can anyone offer any guidance?

Comment: If you post your full code block it will be easier to identify what's happening